# How to get Chirpy to update mashed files when edits are made

Tags: visual-studio, minify, auto-update, chirpy

I've just begun using [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com), and it's frigging amazing. One problem I'm having is that I'm unable to get it to update the mashed file(s) when an edit is made in one of the "sub" files.

IE: If I have a mashed file called "site.css" (via my js.chirp.config file) which contains "elements.css", "master.css", "misc.css" etc.  And I make an edit to one of them (say, master.css), I want chirpy to kick in and redo the site.css with the new edits.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: +1, Chirpy is friggin' amazing but this is a real nuisance.   Maybe one of us should go implement it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chirpy does this - just make sure your paths use backslashes rather than forward slashes.

```
<root>
    <FileGroup Name="site.css">
        <File Path="css\elements.css" />
        <File Path="css\master.css" />
        <File Path="css\misc.css" />
    </FileGroup>
</root>
```

Chirpity chirp chirp chirp.

Comment: this won't allow chirpy to update when I save the CSS, I have to actually save the config file.

Comment: I can confirm that it does allow this - I am using Margogype Chirpy (ver 2.0) - every time a css file is updated and saved, the "site.min.css" file is recreated - look in the output window, show output from Chirpy, and a new line should be created each save

Comment: ah, I just upgraded to v2 - I'll have to see if this works next time I fire it up.

Answer (score 0):

I have

`<Folder Pattern="*.min.css" Minify="false" />`

And with that wildcard in there, it doesnt run when min.css files are updated.  I have to update the config and save for the mash to occur